# Skype stops responding after a while

Tags: ubuntu, skype

I've got a weird problem with Skype running on Ubuntu 9.04.

I installed skype, it starts perfectly and works 100% for a while, then after a while it stops responding, with stop responding I mean it looks like it's working but it isn't, I can open new chat conversations, post messages but the recipients on the other side never receive my messages and it looks like I'm offline. Then I need to Kill skype and start it up again. Then the process repeats itself the whole time. Any solutions for this since I can't find any answers on Google etc.

Latest Update on this problem.

1) No Firewall
2) 2.0.0.72 is the version I use.
3) Sound devices are working

Comment: are you behind a firewall/proxy?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Skype (2.0.0.72)? How is the Sound Devices option configured?

Comment: I updated the problem

Comment: I don't suppose you have a secondary audio device that you could try using?

Comment: No secondary audio device. so as reading the comments, I assume the audio devices could have something to do with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have pulseaudio on your machine, try configuring Skype to use pulse as per the [instructions on the pulseaudio wiki](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/PerfectSetup#Skype). If that doesn't work, look through the [Troubleshooting Skype](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype#Troubleshooting%20Skype) of the Ubuntu Community documentation.

Here's a post on the skype forum that might be of interest: [Skype hang when calling or going to option->sound](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=120431)

I have experienced something similar. The next time Skype stops responding, open up the Options->Sound Devices page and see if you're able to reconfigure the devices. I think this is a common problem with Skype on linux.

Comment: I adjusted my audio settings, so far so good, but will have to see what it does

Comment: so far Skype didn't hang again, I'll give it time till the end of the day

Comment: Seems like my Skype is working now. Thanx alot for the help